# Flask.session doesn't store data

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I try to save serialized `BaseQuery` object to the `flask.session['t']` object but every time the `get request` is sent to this endpoint the `session.get('t')` is `None`.
`q_transactions` is non-empty list.

Could you help me to understand why it behaves that way? Did I miss or missunderstand something?

```
# app.py
@bp.route('/testing')
def testing():
    import sys
    from flask import session
    from sqlalchemy.ext.serializer import loads, dumps

    form = FiltersForm(request.args)

    if session.get('t') is not None:
        print('|'*80)
        print(loads(session.get('t')), file=sys.stdout)
        print('|'*80)


    filters = form.data
    q_transactions = current_user.transactions()
    q_transactions = Transaction.apply_filters(q_transactions, filters)
    session['t'] = dumps(q_transactions)

    return render_template('test_edit_transaction.html', form=form)
```

EDIT:
The issue is probably caused by too large data.

Comment: I have never used it before, but could the session dictionary perhaps only contain strings, and not a serialised object? There’s good info at https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/

Comment: In particular, your code doesn’t show where you initialise the Session object by sending it the app object - e.g. `Session(app)`. Note there also seems to be a specific way to configure it to use SQLAlchemy as the session backend.

Comment: I didn't initialise because I just use built-in `session` (not Flask-Session extension). The problem seems to be that data is too large.

Comment: Ah ok - I’m not familiar with that method.